# Is there a way to set up a warning before executing some commands in the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sudo, gnu

There are some terminal commands that are proficient at destroying large swaths of data very efficiently. Like: `sudo rm -rf /*` or `rm -rf /*`. I want to set up a warning that will show up, whenever these destructive commands are entered. Something like this:

```
sudo rm -rf /*
Are you sure you want to remove all files from your root 
directory recursively? This operation will remove all files from the root 
directory, any mounted filesystems attached to it and essential operating 
system files. 
Are you sure you want to proceed? [Y/n]

rm -rf /*
Are you sure you want to remove all files owned by $USER 
recursively? This operation will remove all your files on the root 
filesystem and any filesystems mounted to it.
Are you sure you want to proceed? [Y/n]
```

How to write a script that does this?

Comment: I feel like you could probably do something like this with extensive scripting of bash's `readline` facility. The toughest part would be creating the regexes or other pattern matching code to define what commands you consider harmful.

Answer (score 1):

`rm` has the option `-i` which asks every time before removing a file. I think that's not what you want because it asks **EVERY** time before removing a file which would often go into many hundreds of acknowledgments if you want to recursively delete, for example, a git repo.

What you want is probably a simple script which "replaces" `rm` like this one

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(ls -l $1 | wc -l)" = "1" ]; then
  rm $1 $@
else
  echo "You are going to delete these ($(ls -l $1 | wc -l)) files/directories via shell globbing" 
  ls $1
  read -p "Do you really want to delete these files? [y/n]" yn
  if [ $yn = [Yy] ]; then
    rm $1 $@
  fi
fi
```

Note: you have to use the script like "rm FILE ARGUMENTS".

This script looks if you choose more than one file (directory) with shell globbing but removes the file if it's only one.

Comment: Worth pointing out.  While you can create a script that you to confirm, a user can still manually use the command, there is no way to prevent the use of the command without breaking the script itself.

Comment: This script is not exactly what I'm looking for, because it would not warn before entering a command in the form rm -[options] [file], which is the standard shell syntax. I'm looking for a script that would warn and ask for confirmation in response to entering rm -r [directory] /* OR ./ .

Comment: We are not a script writing service.

Comment: Isn't there a standard option to protect the root fs? I think `--no-preserve-root` or something deactivated that

Comment: @Ramhound but couldn't you just alias the command to the script? This would prevent most users from making a mistake (not much good to stop an experienced user set on malicious behavior though).

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not asking for you to write me a script. I'm asking if it's possible to write a script that will cover this usage.

Comment: @LostSoul - How else am I suppose to take " I'm looking for a script that would warn and ask for confirmation in response to entering ..."?